# Get video from youtube or file system

Tags: html, video

Just wondering if there is any benefit to loading a video from youtube or any other service vs. loading video from a folder in my site's file structure.

Answer (score 3):

YouTube's CDN probably delivers video to the visitor faster than your server.

YouTube's bandwidth costs you less money than your bandwidth.

YouTube's code for generating multiple video formats, automatic quality switching and subtitling is probably better than your code for doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just to play devil's advocate to [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38986149/6179296), if the original YouTube video gets taken down, you'll have a dead link on your page.  If you host it yourself, you won't lose it when the original creator takes it down (unless you control the account that posted it, in which case this argument is null)

Comment: The question wasn't asking for disadvantages though :)

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm leaving this up as it could be restated as "the benefit of hosting it myself"

Comment: I like both responses. For my purposes, I think I'll just actively use my youtube account and upload the videos I want to use as 'unlisted' strictly for use in my web projects.

Thanks for your prompt responses guys :-)